# Delete user shows error code (Ubuntu 17.10 )

Tags: sudo, users

When i'm trying to delete user with this code `sudo deluser username` than this message occurs

```
Warning: group `username' has no more members.
userdel: user username is currently used by process 14804
/usr/sbin/deluser: `/usr/sbin/userdel username' returned error code 8 Exiting.
```

so, what can i do for that ??

Comment: According to the man page, error code 8 means the user is currently logged in. Is that the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The process with PID 14804 is running as user `username`. This process has to terminate before you can remove the user. You can use

```
ps -o pid,args -p 14804
```

to see what this process is and

```
sudo kill -9 14804
```

to kill it if you are sure you don't need it any more and there's no better way to terminate it.

The "Warning" says that there's a group named `username` of which user `username` is the only member. You probably want to remove it, too:

```
sudo delgroup username
```